# MS Access INSERT INTO statement without values

Tags: ms-access

In a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable] (
    [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
);
```

What is the insert statement to insert a record?

I tried these statements (without success):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
INSERT INTO MyTable () VALUES ()
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ()
INSERT INTO MyTable () VALUES
```

Comment: I think all :) INSERT INTO MyTable, INSERT INTO MyTable () VALUES (), INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES, INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES() INSERT INTO MyTable () VALUES. That's not the right way...

Comment: Thanks for adding that information, could you please update your question? That would make it much more valuable for the future

Comment: There is also the primary key definition but is not influent for the issue.

Comment: Is this a statement you are trying to run inside of Access, or through some other method using a Jet database file? The syntax will change, depending on how you are connecting to it. I ask because the CREATE sql is not Access compatible.

Comment: I'm using it via OleDB. Actually I found a solution via OleDB. I think that there is not a solution inside Microsoft Access (see answer below)

Comment: Never mind. I see you answered your own question with OLEDB sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it... It's the same syntax as SQL Server but in case of MS Access it is undocumented

```
INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES
```

**EDIT**
It works using OleDB.
It does not work inside MS Access 2007 (syntax error on DEFAULT keywork).

Comment: This does not work for me in Access 2007. I get "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: You are right! It works only via OLEDB. I tried it with ADO.Net. I edit the answer